# WooCommerce: Round up/down prices with 2 decimals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding, price

Our payment gateway requires us to have 2 decimals activated in WooCommerce, resulting in the price looking like this: 199.00

The .00 was easy to hide with the official fix from WooCommece

add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );

However, we have encountered problems with products that have a percental discount applied for example all of our product bundles.

The percental discounts make the price not end with .00 and instead random number like .15, .65 and so forth.
How can we fix this so that we round up/down prices

184.15 to 184.00
184.65 to 185.00

Searched Google. Searched Stackoverflow, found some codes not working.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Do you want to hide decimals now, as initially stated, or not, as stated in the discount part?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, you can remove decimal digits from the WooCommerce admin > [General Settings](https://www.dhirenpatel.me/remove-decimals-product-prices-woocommerce/). However, if it does not solve the issue, you can try using [raw_woocommerce_price](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-formatting-functions.html#source-view.600) filter to round the product price. Following code would help do that.

```
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'wp_raw_woocommerce_price_filter', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Function for `raw_woocommerce_price` filter-hook.
 * 
 * @param float        $raw_price      Raw price.
 * @param float|string $original_price Original price as float, or empty string. Since 5.0.0.
 *
 * @return float
 */
function wp_raw_woocommerce_price_filter( $raw_price, $original_price ){

    // converto non-decimal number
    return round($raw_price);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually works for our product bundle products.
The only problem I see is that the decimals are basically "removed"
The prices are never rounded up/down

99.85 results in 99 (should have been 100.00)
99.15 results in 99 (correctly)

Comment: You can change the code a bit (using round function) to round the value. @Andersson77 updated answer

Comment: How? Where do I add the round function in the code you provided?

Comment: Thank you so much, the updated version worked perfectly :)